# Click listener working for recycler view but for other views

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a recycler view with list and one progress bar down on the view cell. When i clicks on the other views, click event happens. But when press on the recycler view items nothing happens. Please tell me the reason for that. I am pasting the code below of oncreateview holder.

```
class MockSeriesViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
    TextView examMeta;
    RecyclerView subjectBubbles;
    BubbleAdapter adapter;
    NumberProgressBar numberProgressBar;


    public MockSeriesViewHolder(final View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        examMeta = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_exam_meta);
        numberProgressBar = (NumberProgressBar) itemView.findViewById(R.id.pb_exam_progress);

        subjectBubbles = (RecyclerView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.rv_subject_bubbles);
        subjectBubbles.setHasFixedSize(true);
        subjectBubbles.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(itemView.getContext(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false));
        adapter = new BubbleAdapter(itemView.getContext());
        subjectBubbles.setAdapter(adapter);

        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    public void renderMockTestSeries(TestSeriesTest test) {
        adapter.setItems(test.getSubjects());
        examMeta.setText(test.getNoOfQuestions() + " QUESTIONS     " + (test.getTimeLimitInSeconds() / 60) + " MINUTES");
        numberProgressBar.setProgress(test.getPercentageOfCompletion());
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        TestSeriesTest series = getItem(getLayoutPosition());
        mListener.onTestSeriesTestClicked(series);
    }
}
```

And click listner class is

```
public interface TestSeriesTestClickListener {
public void onTestSeriesTestClicked(TestSeriesTest mockTest);}
```

Comment: where is the click listener for recycler view.

Comment: it is an another interface

Comment: check now it is added

Comment: Put a log in your `onClick` method to see if it is actually called or not?

Comment: @HamedMomeni it is calling for all except subjectbubbles. How is it happening. Tell me a fix for that?

Comment: @AtHulAntony check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

make a class with the name RecyclerItemClickListener :

```
import android.content.Context;  
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;  
import android.view.GestureDetector;  
import android.view.MotionEvent;  
import android.view.View;

public class RecyclerItemClickListener implements RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener {  
private OnItemClickListener mListener;

public interface OnItemClickListener {
    public void onItemClick(View view, int position);
}

GestureDetector mGestureDetector;

public RecyclerItemClickListener(Context context, OnItemClickListener listener) {
    mListener = listener;
    mGestureDetector = new GestureDetector(context, new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
            return true;
        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView view, MotionEvent e) {
    View childView = view.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(), e.getY());
    if (childView != null && mListener != null && mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(e)) {
        mListener.onItemClick(childView, view.getChildAdapterPosition(childView));
    }
    return false;
}

@Override
public void onTouchEvent(RecyclerView view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
}
}
```

and then add the below code to your activity :

```
recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(  
new RecyclerItemClickListener(context, new  RecyclerItemClickListener.OnItemClickListener() {
  @Override public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
    // TODO Handle item click
  }
})
);
```

that will be all. you can enter your code in OnItemClick where you also get item position

Comment: Any better way than this?

Comment: i guess it is simple enough..if not tell me what exactly u want to do and i will modify it accordingly

Answer (score 0):

> RecyclerItemClickListener

```
public class RecyclerItemClickListener implements RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener {  
private OnItemClickListener mListener;

public interface OnItemClickListener {
    public void onItemClick(View view, int position);
}

GestureDetector mGestureDetector;

public RecyclerItemClickListener(Context context, OnItemClickListener listener) {
    mListener = listener;
    mGestureDetector = new GestureDetector(context, new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
            return true;
        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView view, MotionEvent e) {
    View childView = view.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(), e.getY());
    if (childView != null && mListener != null && mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(e)) {
        mListener.onItemClick(childView, view.getChildAdapterPosition(childView));
    }
    return false;
}

@Override
public void onTouchEvent(RecyclerView view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
}
}
```

> ClickListener

```
recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(  
new RecyclerItemClickListener(context, new RecyclerItemClickListener.OnItemClickListener() {
  @Override public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
    // TODO Handle item click
  }
})
);
```

Comment: Any better way than this?

Comment: this is the best way I have ever used

Comment: accept & upvote this answer if you findout solution by this.

Answer (score 0):

My disposition is that your `subjectBubbles` must contain clickable items inside which prevent the click event to propagate to the parent view.
Check your `BubbleAdapter` to see if you have any click events in there.

Comment: there is no click events